# How to set up this Google analytics segment in Python API

Tags: python, google-analytics

I created a segment in the graphical interface of Google analytics, and I want to reproduce it in the Python API.

The segment is very straightforward. The subset I want is all `pagePath` containing the string `error_PAYPAL`.

I know how to set this as a filter:

```
filter=ga:pagePath=@error_PAYPAL
```

What is the equivalent syntax for the segment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
segment='sessions::condition::ga:pagePath=@error=PAYPAL'
```